# How to deal with a possible fake account?

Tags: discussion, users

There's a user on Stack Overflow named "[Warren P](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84704/warren-p)" who is very commonly seen under the `delphi` tag. Today, I see [another user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6684540/warren-p) with the exact same name, who created an account 2 days ago, and has posted a few answers. The quality of this other user's posts are nowhere close to the original "Warren P". It seems to me that this user is pretending to be the original "Warren P".

I cannot imagine such a user with almost 30k reputation had to create another account - and I also cannot imagine that there's someone else with precisely the same name who just happens to be familiar with the same topics.

I've already flagged [one of this user's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38816490/988445) for moderator attention.

I'm both raising attention to this, and asking, how should we deal with this?

Comment: Raising for moderator attention is enough (given that you explained what the problem is in the custom text).

Comment: Do note however that duplicate names are not disallowed. So unless he is actively performing malicious activities on the site, there is "no problem" with a second Warren P posting content that does not live up to the Warren P legacy.

Comment: Got a similar case recently here:http://stackoverflow.com/users/6687679/jake-wickham / http://stackoverflow.com/users/6682904/jake-wickham Successfully solved for having mod attention. Perhaps all the accounts should be simply nuked.

Comment: I'm almost expecting someone to create another `Jerry Dodge` account just to prove a point to me...

Comment: Don't think we aren't onto your game, *fake Jerry Dodge!*

Comment: The real Warren-P here, the other one was definitely fake.  It may be impossible to deal with all fakes, but I appreciate Jerry's efforts to improve the quality of community around here. Good work, friend!

Comment: I remember that day that everybody became Jon Skeet (Apr 1st, 2013)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is nothing we can or will do about this. Display names are not required to be unique. Unless the user is intentionally impersonating another user (e.g. they started using their profile picture too), there's nothing wrong with them having the same display name. It's not unreasonable to assume that there are many people with the first name Warren and the last initial P in this world. In fact, there's quite a few more in our system than just these two.

Comment: I may just call myself "Genuine Pekka 웃" from now on then ...

Comment: I may just create an account named Jon Skeet then - but I'll never live up to the reputation of the real Jon Skeet :-)

Comment: @Bart You'll have to start selling Gucci handbags to convince anyone of that.

Comment: @animuson _"There is nothing we can or will do about this."_ Well, we can still be just conscious and not assume bad or abusive behavior, but there are cases. See my comment at the question.

Comment: You don't have to bother with trying to be unique when you're the best.

Comment: Dear @animuson, I have a question, if a user creates another account to answer the question only, and do not upvote or downvote any q/a, and only answers the questions, would it be deserved to be deleted?